# HighCharts - different tooltip in "arearange" and "spline"?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

have found that the tooltip between column and arearange charts is different. I would also like to see the tooltip to the side of the mousepointer - PIC 1. And not centered in the middle - PIC 2. How can I do that? I did not find anything in the API reference.

Thank you for your help and best regards,
Chris

** UPDATE **

Have a look: The "blue" tooltip (1st pic) is what I want for the 2nd pic below. Can anybody help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @282solutions, The solution also work with `column` series. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4957/

Answer (score 0):

The difference results from the fact that a tooltip is related with points. In the first example there is used only one series - `arearange`. On the other hand, in the second example there is a chart with two series - `line` and `arearange`.

In that case with enabled `tooltip.shared` configuration, a tooltip shows every point with the same `x` value.

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

Comment: Sorry doesn't work :-(
I've added two pics above - take a look.

Comment: Hi @282solutions, Use `pointFormat` option to customize your tooltip. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hj1Lktv5/

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to change the pointerFormat. My question was anonther one....

Comment: So please describe precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: The tooltip between column and arearange charts is different. I would also like to see the tooltip to the side of the mousepointer - PIC 1. And not centered in the middle - PIC 2. How can I do that? I did not find anything in the API reference.

Comment: As I have already  explained, the difference results from the fact that `arearange` is one series. The chart with columns and spline is created by using two series. That causes a different format and position of the tooltip. If you want to change the default tooltip position, use: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner